# Conditionally round values with greater than certain amount of decimals

Tags: r

I have a column with a bunch of values and some are behaving weird, I was wondering how would I go about rounding values that have greater than 6 decimal values only to one decimal place?

```
x <- c("5.89", "5.88888888888889")
results <-  c("5.89", "5.9")
```

Comment: Try: `as.character(ifelse(grepl('\\.\\d{7,}',x ) == TRUE, round(as.numeric(x), 1) ,as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: I have some concerns about this question, the data, and assumptions about it. Why does it seem right to arbitrarily "dumb down" values like this? Are your "values" truly strings, or are they originally numbers? To my, `5.888*9` could easily be related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), meaning that is isn't behaving weird, it is behaving correctly per IEEE-754. Lastly, having varying significant digits in the same column might imply in this case that you only have 2 signif digits, so `5.89` is really just `5.9`.

Comment: @r2evans I've run into this sort of problem when passing data from R into SQLite and back, since it goes through character conversion in the process. I agree that they should probably just all be rounded to the same number of digits though.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I've not run into problems like that between R and SQLite. SQLite supports numbers natively (unlike other data types such as timestamps), so it should not be using strings anywhere. Are there any documented examples of this happening?

Comment: In particular, I've noticed it when I make dump files for backups. Maybe it's only happening at that step, not in the direct interchange using DBI.

Comment: So it's a problem not with sqlite, but in how `write.csv` (or whatever) renders your R `numeric` to a file? (I don't mean to hijack this question, so perhaps we should continue this conversation in a [quick chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212638/quick-chat).)